# STM32 board recognized as mass storage device

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to program STM32F407VET6 board and it is recognized in Device Manager as an Mass Storage Device. I've tried to change driver to libusb-win32, but now it looks like this:

[image: mcudev in Device Manager]

Before and after driver reinstall ST-Link Utility says "No ST-LINK detected !". Board was just bought new and came as it is.

I'm new to STM32 programming and maybe missed some important details.

Comment: If memory serves, the boards can power up in either of two modes; I think holding a button on startup will switch between them.  In one mode, it behaves as a mass storaage device, and copying a properly-formatted file to it will program the firmware.  In the other mode, they are designed for use with ST-Link.

Comment: Just tried, no result. Also tried to connect BOOT0/BOOT1 to vdd - no result

Comment: If the board powers up as a mass-storage device, what does it contain?

Comment: There is two volumes first one is 2mb and it is empty, the second one is "not accesible" when trying to view inside it

Comment: Weird.  The systems that I've seen that are programmed based on the Mass Storage Device interface include some explanatory files in the disk image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Connecting the BT0 pin to the 3V3 pin and connecting the BT1 pin to GND apparently puts the pin in DFU mode, after which your STM32 will start showing up as "STM32 bootloader" in the device manager.
[refer this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUPEI.png)

Now, you can use the STM32 CubeProgrammer connected in USB mode along with the Arduino IDE using the STMduino libraries and run generic arduino code on your STM32.

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4c8AYkBeEvU)

Comment: Tried this solution multiple times. Ended up with buying st-link v2 and flashed stm successfully.